# My Hide option from dropdown 2 when selected in dropdown 1 is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My Hide option from dropdown 2 when selected in dropdown 1 is not working? I have also included my code below please give me some suggestions why it is not working, I am stuck from two days ...

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <script>$('select').selectpicker();</script>



    <style>
        nav {
            background: #4776E6;
            /* fallback for old browsers */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #8E54E9, #4776E6);
            /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #8E54E9, #4776E6);
            /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <!-- Upload Button -->
        <form method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button onclick="onSubmitBtn()" type="submit" id="btn-hide" class="btn btn-danger">Upload</button>
        </form>

        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea3">Total Number of Rows:</label>
        <input type="number" id="Text1" name="TextBox1">

        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea4">Total Number of Outliers:</label>
        <input type="number" id="Text2" name="TextBox2">
    </nav>

    </br></br>

    <!-- <select class="dropdown selectpicker" id="dropdown1" data-live-search="True"> -->

    <!-- <select class="dropdown selectpicker" id="dropdown2" multiple data-live-search="True"> -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <select class="selectpicker" name="dropdown1" data-live-search="True">
        <!-- {% for entry in item %}
        <option name="dCol" value="{{ entry }}">{{ entry }}</option>
        {% endfor %} -->

        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
        <option>D</option>
        <option>E</option>
    </select>

    <select class="selectpicker" name="dropdown2" multiple data-live-search="True">
        <!-- {% for entry in item %}
        <option name="iCol" value="{{ entry }}">{{ entry }}</option>
        {% endfor %} -->

        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
        <option>D</option>
        <option>E</option>
    </select>

    <!--Script tag-->
    <script>
        var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='dropdown1']");
        var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='dropdown2']");

        $dropdown1.change(function () {
        $dropdown2.empty().append($dropdown1.find('option').clone());
        var selectedItem = $(this).val();
        if (selectedItem) {
            $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').remove();
        }
        });
    </script>

    </br></br>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <!--  Html Table -->
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-dark">
            <tr>
                {% for value in DataFrame %}
                <th>{{ value }}</th>
                {% endfor %}

                {% for _,row in DataFrame.iterrows %}
            <tr>
                {% for value in row %}
                <td>{{ value }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

Is there anything wrong in my javascript code or something else? The dropdown 2 is multiple select with search bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your javascript/jquery code in document ready event. Also you need to set value property to your dropdown options. And after rebind you need to call **$dropdown2.selectpicker('refresh');**

Here is the [Live Demo](http://www.toolbow.com/code-editor/67c5a445-e5cd-4b63-947f-7f4744abf0e1/clone-dropdown-values)

```
 var $dropdown1;
 var $dropdown2;
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('select').selectpicker();
        $dropdown1 = $("select[name='dropdown1']");
        $dropdown2 = $("select[name='dropdown2']");
        $dropdown1.on("change",function () {

        $dropdown2.find("option").remove();
        $dropdown2.append($dropdown1.find('option').clone());
        var selectedItem = $(this).val();
        if (selectedItem) {
            $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').remove();
        }
      $dropdown2.selectpicker('refresh');

        });


});
```